# Is it possible to know which is the correct temperature range and speed for any model?

Tags: 3d-models, simplify3d, speed

Trying to print a 3D model for my mobile phone, but I see that when printing the sides, being thin, increases the retraction and the recoil seems a little abrupt and makes a coarse sound.

I would like to know if it is possible to know what speed and temperature is recommended to print a model.

In my case I use Simplify3D, and when I'm going to save the file in `.gcode` format, I see that there are some ranges shown in colors, how does this apply to the models?

[image: Screenshot of Simplify3D]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first indication for print speed and temperature should be taken from the box the filament comes in. Generally it specifies temperature ranges for the hotend and the heated bed. Sometime, mostly online, more parameters can be found amongst which is the printing speed.

Do note that temperature and printing speed are linked, if you want to print faster you should increase the temperature. But, if you are printing small or thin things you should print slower so that the part cools enough for the next layer. Basically, part cooling is then also important, but not all filament types (e.g. the ones with a high melt temperature like ABS or PETG) like being cooled too much. So you have another parameter to consider.

It is difficult to instruct you to print at a certain speed and certain temperatures as it is highly depending on the filament (e.g. also the filament diameter), the machine type/make and model, extruder setup (direct or Bowden), the print, enclosure, etc.

Because of the many parameters affecting printing, it is usually suggested to calibrate the printer by printing a [temperature tower](/a/7346/) or performing [retraction tests](/q/8194/) to find the print window for your specific setup.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, my filaments mostly have temperature rangue between 180 °C - 220 °C (356 F - 428 F), and the speed 50 mm/s - 100 mm/s. 

My Printir is Core XY DIY, have a bowden extruder, the extruder is E3D V6. I was investigate and make question, and  some recommended to me layer fan, what you think?

I am using PLA Glow in the dark. The brands of my filaments is Amolen.

Comment: Note that most dye's used for glow in the dark require a hardened nozzle. You probably have PLA, this print perfectly at about 195-200 °C at about 60 mm/s, you can increase the temp range to 210-220 °C if you want to print up to 100 mm/s. Print some tests, e.g. heat towers at different speeds to find out what works best for you.

Comment: But, if use 210 - 220 °C range, and the 60 mm/s, this will be the opposite the teory, when the temperature is high, the speed too, obvious this is directy proportional?, well i have to practice with the some tower and how separate process with simplify, o what software you recommended for this?

Comment: 3dSimplify calculates according area, infill and borders vs your settings, but you can override with higher values. The calculated values were taken by some testing which developers made before releasing his software, new version has new parameters to improve your printings. Of course you can calculate your owns.

Answer (score 2):

So as someone else on here mention, those settings shouldn't be for the model but for the filament. Sadly, you will need to test 99% of filaments to really figure this out. I have a modify tester, and on the description it tells you how to set your temp. https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:3347967

You can look at the remix if you want to grab the blank model and put your own numbers on it.
It should be noted that things like water in the filament can mess with how the filament reacts to speed and temp. If you have questionable prints coming out of a filament that sat there for a long time. You can easily run it through the test to figure out the temp.

Anything else I could add is would just repeat what most of 0scar said.

Comment: a different filament in this is "a different combination of manufacturer, color and plastic type"